# Is it acceptable for comments to turn into a back and forth debugging session?

Tags: discussion

In the process of answering a question, comments have digressed into a back and forth debugging session.  Is that generally accepted?  Is there a better approach to helping a user?

Comment: You use comments to ask the OP for clarification not debate.  If its debating generally speaking a mod can move it to chat.

Comment: No. SO is not a remote debugging service.

Comment: In this case it's not debate, it's lack of understanding on how to implement the solution. :-/

Comment: Thanks.  Was not familiar with a chat feature.  Will dig into it.

Comment: @JonH note that after a certain amount of to and fro'ing in comments, the system will generate an auto "continue this conversation in chat" link which can be used for the users to do so themselves...

Comment: If an OP is asking new questions in a comment, that's a good indication they're a help vampire.  Just politely tell them to get stuffed... uh, I mean, tell them to work on it and if they can't figure it out ask a new question about it.

Comment: Yeah, you should understand that many posters are clueless.  I mean totally clueless - they have copied the code from other students, or some web page, and have no chance whatsoever of implementing any kind of fix and expect complete, working code, including how to build it, test it and deliver it to their prof/TA as if their own work.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you answer/solve the user's issue in the comments, you run the risk of either 1) The OP deleting their question, so you can't post an answer, 2) The OP self-answering with the solution, 3) A 3rd party posting the solution as an answer as soon as it appears and the OP accepting that.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there are a lot of comments back and forth about what's going on, then **the question isn't clear enough to be answered by any passer-by.**

In that event, the question should be put on hold until the OP can add the details to their question.

If you find yourself in this scenario, you can do one of two things:

- Move the conversation to Chat so that this sort of conversation can happen both in real time and without the long comment chain, or
- Politely ask the OP to clarify what it is they're trying to do and walk away until they do so.

Comment: So when one of the commenters has a reputation less than that required to chat what happens when it's moved to chat?

Comment: @infixed:  Then the person initiating the conversation should *instead* encourage the OP to edit their question and include the missing details there.